# Extracting data from large xml file with the aid of xslt using node path in python and

Tags: python, xml, sqlite, xslt

I am new to **xslt**. I want to extract from a large xml file some info using python. I learnt that to convert my heavily nested xml file into a flat file, I need to transform the xml file into xsl file format, but have little understanding of xslt syntax. My xml file ([DUMMY XML FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsODUzbWpQbm5SaWM/view?usp=sharing)). My desired goal is to extract into sqlite databse a table with columns names as UltimateHoldingCompany Name, OrganisationName, CompanyID

From the dummy file, paths to this info are:

```
OrganisationName = N8:EntityList/N8:Entity/N2:OrganisationName/N2:NameElement
CompanyID = N8:EntityList/N8:Entity/N5:Identifiers/N5:Identifier/N5:IdentifierElement
UltimateHoldingCompanyName =  N8:EntityList/N8:Entity/N9:UltimateHoldingCompany/N2:OrganisationName/N2:NameElement
```

My **python** code is this:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import sqlite3

def insert_program(db_conn, companyID, companyNAME, ultimateHOLDINGcompanyName):
    curs = db_conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("insert into program values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", (companyID, companyNAME, ultimateHOLDINGcompanyName))
    db_conn.commit()

def program_data_from_element(element):
    companyID = element.find("companyID").text
    companyNAME = element.find("companyNAME").text
    ultimateHOLDINGcompanyName = element.find("ultimateHOLDINGcompanyName").text

    return companyID, companyNAME, ultimateHOLDINGcompanyName

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    conn = sqlite3.connect("program.sqlite3")
    xml = ET.parse("ompanies_xml_extract_20170703NEW.xml")

# PROGRAM PARSE
xslt = ET.parse("program.xsl")
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(xml)
program = newdom.xpath("//program")    

for index, element in enumerate(program):
    companyID, companyNAME, ultimateHOLDINGcompanyName = program_data_from_element(element)
    insert_program(conn, companyID, companyNAME, ultimateHOLDINGcompanyName)
```

My **xslt** code is this:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/N8:EntityList">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="N8:Entity/N2:OrganisationName">
        <Report_Entry>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../N2:NameElement"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="../N2:NameElement/*">
                <xsl:element name="N2:NameElement">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../N9:UltimateHoldingCompany"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="../N2:NameElement/*">
                <xsl:element name="N2:OrganisationName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Report_Entry>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Running the code gave this result:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" D:/my_pythoncode.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/my_pythoncode.py", line 1, in <module>
import lxml.etree as ET
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

Thanks.